# TGridPanel no transparency if themes disabled in Win7

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a form filled with a TImage. I put over this a TGridPanel. If themes are enabled in Windows 7 the TGirdPanel appears with transparency. If themes are disabled (no visual styles) the TGridPanel loses transparency and hides the part it ocupies. I use Delphi XE2

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a basic fact of life for panels. It's not special to the `TGridPanel`, you will see the same effect for any control derived from `TCustomPanel`. The transparency is only supported when the application is themed.

The grid panel is just a convenient way to layout your controls. If you want to support running unthemed then the simplest solution is to remove the `TGridPanel` and layout your controls manually. That's pretty much trivial to do. Handle the `OnResize` event of the control that currently contains the panel, and position your controls as desired.

Comment: TJvPanel however has the Transparent property, but there is no TJvGridPanel :(